# Qt XML duplicate tags

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have a xml file and just want to duplicate some specific nodes:

From (example):

```
<1>
 <2>
 </2>
</1>
```

to:

```
<1>
 <2>
 </2>
 <2>
 </2>
</1>
```

I tried the following:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < xmlRoot.childNodes().count(); i++)    {
    if(xmlRoot.childNodes().at(i).isElement()){
        if(xmlRoot.childNodes().at(i).toElement().attribute("id") == "teamSection"){ //find goal element
            teamNode = xmlRoot.childNodes().at(i).cloneNode(); //copy element

            if(xmlRoot.childNodes().at(i).insertAfter(teamNode, xmlRoot.childNodes().at(i)).isNull()){
                qDebug() << "not worked";
            }
            else{
                qDebug() << "worked";
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

But I think I misunderstand the refChiled - cause my solution just return null. (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdomnode.html - insertAfter). How can I duplicate a simple node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
xmlRoot.childNodes().at(i).insertAfter(teamNode, xmlRoot.childNodes().at(i))
```

The `insertAfter` method takes two arguments - the new node and the node that will be a reference for the new node insertion. But, both of these arguments need to be a children of common parent on which `insertAfter` is invoked. Schematically, your code is like `child->insertAfter(newChild, child)` while it should be `parent->insertAfter(newChild, child)`. You can have a look at the code below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < xmlRoot.childNodes().count(); i++)
{
    if (xmlRoot.childNodes().at(i).isElement())
    {
        if(xmlRoot.childNodes().at(i).toElement().attribute("id") == "teamSection")
        {
            auto teamNode = xmlRoot.childNodes().at(i).cloneNode(); //copy element
            auto sibling = xmlRoot.childNodes().at(i);

            if (xmlRoot.insertAfter(teamNode, sibling).isNull())
            {
                qDebug() << "not worked";
            }
            else
            {
                qDebug() << "worked";
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```